# CVS check out earlier date

Tags: cvs, wincvs

Am using WinCVS, need to check out the whole project branch as it was on an earlier date... How would i do it....

Thanks a lot,
Vinod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinCvs you can specify the date to check out on the "Update Options" tab of the Checkout dialog (Remote|Checkout module).

Answer (score -1):

```
> cvs -H co
Usage:
  cvs checkout [-ANPRcflnps] [-r rev] [-D date] [-d dir]
    [-j rev1] [-j rev2] [-k kopt] modules...
    [...]
    -P  Prune empty directories.
    [...]
    -r rev  Check out revision or tag. (implies -P) (is sticky)
    -D date Check out revisions as of date. (implies -P) (is sticky)
```

Comment: thanks Thariama, Oliver Giesen and just somebody... Going back in code is something i would never wish tu du... But pain is i have tu nw... :|

thanks guys...